# Difference between calling an Arrow Function and a Function in a Props pass - REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, arrow-functions

I have that component:

```
 <SelectCampanha
          titulo="Preenchimento obrigatório"
          listaOpcoes={
             category
              ? riskModel.filter((item) =>
                  item.CategoryType.includes(categoria)
                )
              : riskModel}
        />
```

Now I want to pass this filter to a function

```
const filter = () => {
 return category
   ? riskModel.filter((item) =>
   item.CategoryType.includes(categoria)
   )
  : riskModel
}
```

I would like to know the difference between calling an Arrow Function and a Function in a Props pass.

What is the correct way to call this function in the component?

```
<SelectCampanha
      titulo="Preenchimento obrigatório"
      listaOpcoes={filter()}
/>
```

or

```
<SelectCampanha
      titulo="Preenchimento obrigatório"
      listaOpcoes={() => filter()}
/>
```

When I used the last option, it seems that it ran the function once and there was no time to update the state of the variables

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know the difference between calling an Arrow Function and a Function in a Props pass.

In Javascript a function is called when `functionName()` appears (note the `()`). Usually you want to pass a function to your component in order to call it later on (for example as a click handler inside of the component) rather then passing the `return value` of a function to the component.

```
function myMethod() {
  return 1
}
```

`<MyComponent myPassedMethod={myMethod} myPassedValue={myMethod()} />`

In the given example the `props` of `MyComponent` would be like so:

```
{
  myPassedMethod: // function definition of "myMethod"
  myPassedValue: 1 //return value of "myMethod"
}
```

So when you pass the filter method like so:

`listaOpcoes={filter()}`

you will pass the `return value` of `filter()`.

If you pass it like so:

`listaOpcoes={() => filter()}`

a `function` is passed to the component props which could be called inside the component later on.

Maybe this example of two equivalent expressions does also clarify things a bit:

`listaOpcoes={filter()}` is equivalent to `listaOpcoes={() => { return filter()}()}`

Answer (score 0):

Passing a function is not the same as passing its returned value.

When you pass `filter()`, it will get called and the **returned value** will be passed.
Alternatively, if you pass `() => filter()` it's identical to passing `filter` - and then you pass the actual **function**. This is useful when you want to decopule the calculation from the context the function is being passed in.

In your case, it seems like you want to wrap the calculation in the `filter` function, so you need to pass `filter()` as the prop - since you're using its result as the actual prop.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your prop is expecting if you want to pass filtered items you should avoid arrow function and use

```
<SelectCampanha
      titulo="Preenchimento obrigatório"
      listaOpcoes={filter()}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no canonical ways of passing props. Both options are correct though. It depends on how you want to interpret the prop you have passed.

### The First Option

You call the filter function and **pass the returned value from the function as a prop** to the `SelectCampanha` component.

For example, to use the prop in the `SelectCampanha` component (using the first option to pass the prop):

```
export function SelectCampanha({ listaOpcoes }) {

     // listaOpcoes is an array!
     listaOpcoes.map(item => ...)

}
```

### The Second Option

You **pass an anonymous function which returns the returned value of the filter function** as a prop to the `SelectCampanha` component.

For example, to use the prop in the `SelectCampanha` component (using the second option to pass the prop):

```
export function SelectCampanha({ listaOpcoes }) {

     // listaOpcoes is a function!
     // Firstly, we call the function to get the returned array
     const data = listaOpcoes()

     // data is an array returned from the filter() function
     data.map(item => ...)
    
}
```